# Capital Omega problem, I can not renewcommand it

Tags: symbols

I want to change all the `\Omega` in my paper into `\varOmega`, but always receive an error information. Here is the details.

I have add the line in the preamble `\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}` when I compile the TeX file, it said that

```
Command `\Omega' already defined. \begin{document}
```

Because there are too many `\Omega`, it is almost impossible to change them one by one. Therefore I want to use `\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}` to realize my purpose. What is wrong with my method?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}
\usepackage{xeCJK} 
\begin{document} 
$\Omega$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's strange. Can you narrow down the problem in terms of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? For example, a document with only `\Omega` in it together with the current preamble? Or even sequentially removing packages from the preamble until the problem goes away?

Comment: the following works fine for me: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}
\begin{document}
$\Omega$
\end{document}`

Comment: The following works fine for me too: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}
\begin{document}
Here is a test for $\Omega$
\end{document}
But when I insert the line 
\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}
into my previous huge tex-file, it does not work fine anymore. It always give the information below:
Command `\Omega' already defined.
It is very strange!

Comment: @azhi make a *copy* of your 'huge' file, add the command, and start stripping it while keeping the error- this will get you close to a MWE that you can post in your question :)

Comment: If you are gonna change ALL `\Omega` in the file, why not just use some text editor to do find/replace?

Comment: I do not want to change all the \Omega into \varOmega, for there are almost 50 files in sum, each one of which contains many \Omega.

Comment: I have found the reason!  Here is my MWE, you can check if xeCJK package will conflict with that command line I gave before: 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
 $\Omega$
\end{document}

Answer (score 8):

Redefine `\Omega` at the beginning of the document, that is replace

```
\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}
```

with

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{xeCJK} 
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}}

\begin{document} 
$\Omega$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may want to pass the `no-math` option to `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage[no-math]{xeCJK} 

\setCJKmainfont{SimSun} % this one I have on my machine

\renewcommand{\Omega}{\varOmega}

\begin{document} 
$\Omega$ 
\end{document}
```